# Why does my checkout of an upstream PR not contain the latest commit?

Tags: git, local, pull-request

I'm able to see this PR with the commit of "c12b34" (made few days ago) using the following cmd

```
git ls-remote upstream
c12b34afadc4df762eaa482984170974c6f6b1c0        refs/pull/35/head
```

I then checkout the PR. But log does not contain the above commit; it only shows commits up to few months back.

```
git checkout -b upstream/35
```

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: tried git fetch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `git checkout -b`, you create a local name—a branch name—based on some commit that you *already have*.  You probably do not have the commit(s) you need.  You will need to run `git fetch` to obtain those commits.

Those commits, however, are found by consulting a name in a name-space that your Git would ordinarily *not* bring over.  You will need to run, e.g.:

```
git fetch upstream refs/pull/35/head:refs/heads/pr/35
```

to (a) obtain the commit(s) and then (b) create a local branch named `pr/35`, for instance.  No separate `git checkout -b` is required at this point as the `fetch` operation created `refs/heads/pr/35`, which is a branch named `pr/35` in your repository.

(Remember to delete your name `pr/35` when done with it.)

Comment: The above fetch of the specific PR works. I _did_ do a 'git fetch upstream' (without a specific ref) but that did not work. Why is that?

Comment: @Myloti: The `refs/pull/` name-space is outside the default set of names that your Git will bring over. That's why GitHub use it: it is not in your way because you don't use it. If you choose to use it, you're choosing to use their names.